# Outlook Add-in: move email to specific folder

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

Outlook Add-ins are allowed to move emails to specific folder or even deleted folder?
If yes how can be done?
I didn't find anything about on the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EWS or [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) for that. See [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information about EWS. More information specific to Outlook web add-ins can be found in the [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) article.